# Meaning of ":keywords" in Ruby on Rails Search Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, keyword

I started learning RoR by myself with the help of a book that shows how to build a Webapp step by step. But sometime I still dont understand the code.

Here's an extract of a code I dont understand. What does :keywords mean and how does such kind of **:xxx** structure call in Rails?

```
<section class="search-form">
 <%= form_for :customers, method: :get do |f| %>
      <div class="input-group input-group-lg">
      <%= label_tag :keywords, nil, class: "sr-only" %> 
      <%=text_field_tag :keywords, nil,
      placeholder: "First Name, Last Name, or Email Address", class: "form-control input-lg" %>
           <span class="input-group-btn">
                <%= submit_tag "Find Customers",
                class: "btn btn-primary btn-lg" %>
           </span>
      </div>
 <% end %> 
 </section>
```

Comment: It will be the parameter which you pass to controller and search with the value.

Answer (score 0):

`:xxx` is a [*Symbol literal*](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Symbol.html) - it is a Ruby construct, not specific to Rails, that *evaluates to a Symbol object*.

> Symbol objects represent names and some strings inside the Ruby interpreter. They are generated using the :name and :"string" literals syntax, and by the various to_sym methods. ***The same Symbol object will be created for a given name or string for the duration of a program's execution***, regardless of the context or meaning of that name.

In a way, symbols are like integer values: 42 is always 42 and :foo is always :foo. That is, the literals identify unique values.

The usage of the `:keywords` symbol - or any symbol, *which is just a value* - depends on specific API. In this case it is used to [*give a name to a text field*](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/label_tag):

> label_tag(name = nil, ..)

This name is *also* later supplied to the `text_field_tag`; in both cases the *same Symbol* (same as in *same object*) was supplied to both methods.

While, for the most part, RoR will quite happily work with Strings, using Symbols can reduce the number of created string objects *and* makes the intent of the code - eg. "this is a name of something" - more clear.

---

That is, both of the forms shown below are equivalent. Only the Symbol version has a chance of object reduction: since there is lots of Symbol-to-String conversions this is a '*chance*', with different levels of outcome, and by no means a guarantee that Symbols will result in "less" objects in the RoR case.

With Symbols for names:

```
<%= label_tag :name_for_label, .. %>
<%= text_field_tag :name_for_label, .. %>
```

With Strings for names:

```
<%= label_tag 'name_for_label', .. %> 
<%= text_field_tag 'name_for_label', .. %>
```

And .. the result of the output is identical ..